# QGIS android problem on load

Tags: qgis, android

I am new to both android and QGIS, but have 20 yrs experience with MapInfo and ArcGIS.
I have installed QGIS on a nexus 7 (4.2),  but keep getting the error :

> No qgis data provider plugins found in /data/app_lib/lib No vector
>   layers can be loaded.

Comment: Could you post: - the apk version you used - the logcat of the problem You can see the logcat (android logs) by using the adb logcat command on your pc (if you have the android SDK) or directly on the device using the alogcat free application available in the market. I've never seen that error.

Comment: I'm working on this.
This is due to the new folder structure from android 4.2. (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835808/are-the-library-location-on-android-4-2-1-moved))
I'll release an update soon. keep an eye on [my blog](http://www.opengis.ch/tech-blog/)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like it may well be able to solve your issue:

http://www.opengis.ch/2012/11/24/fixed-workaround-version/

**UPDATE 03/02/13:**

I'm now experiencing the same "No qgis data provider..." error when building from source (also on Nexus 7 [Android 4.2]).

I've pasted the output of logcat for both the installation and launching of QGIS on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/zLRjGxGj).

I used the .apk found here:

http://android.qgis.org/download/apk/release/qgis-9-armeabi.apk